# how to disable part of the page's codes after clicking on a a href?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create tickets system, the idea is to fetch all the tickets beside the new ticket form in the same page, I want when someone click on the ticket the tickets and the new ticket form should disappear and open the ticket with the response form in the same page. I mean when someone clicks on the ticket I want everything to disappear expect the responses form. Please Help.

```
     print ("
     <form action='<?php echo $PHP_SELF;?>' method='post' class='f'>
     <input type='text' name='subject' placeholder='العنوان'></input>
     <textarea name='tmessage' placeholder='الموضوع'></textarea>
     <input type='submit' name='t_submit' value='انشاء'></input>
     </form>");
     $tsubject=$_POST['subject'];
     $tmessage=$_POST['tmessage'];
     $tsubmit=$_POST['t_submit'];
     $ttdate=date ("Y-m-d");
     if(isset($tsubmit)){

     $int=mysql_query("INSERT INTO tickets(id,u_id,message,subject,date,status) 

     VALUES('','$_SESSION[id]','$tmessage','$tsubject','$ttdate','0')");

     if($int) { echo "تم انشاء التذكرة بنجاح";} else{ echo "خطاء"; }

     }
     $gtk=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tickets WHERE u_id='$_SESSION[id]'");
     while($ftk=mysql_fetch_object($gtk)){
     if($ftk->status == 0) { $tkst= "معلقة"; }
     if($ftk->status == 1) { $tkst= "مجابه"; }
     print("<a href='tickets.php?tkid=$ftk->id' class='f'>$ftk->subject</a> . 

     $tkst");
     }
     $tkid=$_GET['tkid'];

     $uig=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='$_SESSION[id]'");
     $fuig=mysql_fetch_object($uig);
     $gm=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tickets WHERE id='$tkid'");
     $fgm=mysql_fetch_object($gm);
     print ("<fieldset>
     <legend>$fuig->username </legend>
     $fgm->message
     </fieldset>");
     $grs=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM responses WHERE t_id='$tkid' ORDER BY id 

     ASC");
     while($fgrs=mysql_fetch_object($grs)){

     print("$fgrs->response <br>");

     }
     print("
     <form action='<?php echo $PHP_SELF;?>' method='post'>
     <textarea name='response'></textarea>
     <input type='submit' name='rsubmit' value='ارسل'></input>
     </form>
     ");
     $response=$_POST ['response'];
     $rsubmit=$_POST ['rsubmit'];
     $tdate=date ("Y-m-d");
     if(isset($rsubmit)){


     $ir=mysql_query("INSERT INTO responses(id,t_id,response,r_date) VALUES

     ('','$tkid','$response','$tdate')");
     if($ir) { echo "تم ارسال الرد";
     } else { echo "خطاء";}
     }




        ?>
```

Comment: 1) it's better if you migrate to mysqli or pdo statement instead of mysql_* (deprecated). 2) you can escape php and print html in other mode. 3) put a javascript var set to false, on the click you can put it to true, all you want to block, set it will run only if the var is false.

Comment: You definitively should consider using JS to perform this process, because PhP communicate with the server to send a plain HTML file, so you can't reset only a part of your HTML view. JavaScript provides somes objects to do so.